# How to fix ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: php, apache

I have a php page which throws the below error often once in ten time of accessing the url, I checked it may be Apache error so contacted hosting team to reboot and rebooted php kill functions

Increased Max execution time too but still i face this error

```
The example.com page isn’t working

example.com didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Let me know if anyone has idea on this.

Comment: If you're running php 5.5. or later, try to disable APC module, it is not needed anyway. For some people this was causing the same error. Also if you have disabled error_reporting, enable it, to see if there are any side errors.

Comment: Enable display_error in PHP. sometimes you get this when page throws PHP errors but display_error is disabled.

Comment: @NikolayGanovski is right !

Comment: My php version is 5.3 and i enabled the error reporting i can see only Notice errors like 'headers already sent'